# Hibernate + Postgres Dettached entity with native query

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have this entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "stats_search")
public class Search implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "stats_search_uuid")
    @Type(type="pg-uuid")
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="city_id", nullable=false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    private City city;

    @Column
    private Double lat;

    @Column
    private Double lng;

    @Column
    private Integer radius;

    @Column(name = "search_time")
    private LocalDateTime searchTime;

    @Column(name = "ip_address")
    private String ipAddress;

}
```

And this repository:

```
public interface StatSearchRepository extends JpaRepository<Search, UUID> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT stats_search.* FROM stats_search " +
            "WHERE ip_address = :ipAddress " +
            "AND search_time > (NOW() - ((INTERVAL '1 seconds') * :delay)) " +
            "ORDER BY search_time DESC LIMIT 1",
            nativeQuery = true)
    Search findIpAddress(String ipAddress, Integer delay);
}
```

But, when I edit the returned object (by editing one of its properties) and call save(), I get an exception because its PK is allready assigned. I think it's because my object is detached.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your method in a transaction to see if it makes any difference?
Try adding `@Transactional` to the method and remove the call to `save()` since the entity will be updated automatically when the method exits. Also, can you show us the code for fetching and updating the entity?

Comment: Without a stacktrace it's impossible to help. Please update the question.